# Lumen PHPUnit test validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, lumen

How to PHPUnit form validation on lumen?
This is because I am receiving the following error.

```
BadMethodCallException: Method [validateTest] does not exist.

C:\work\test\vendor\illuminate\validation\Validator.php:3360
C:\work\test\vendor\illuminate\validation\Validator.php:517
C:\work\test\vendor\illuminate\validation\Validator.php:517
C:\work\test\vendor\illuminate\validation\Validator.php:431
C:\work\test\vendor\illuminate\validation\Validator.php:456
C:\work\test\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Routing\ProvidesConvenienceMethods.php:63
C:\work\test\app\Http\Controllers\BusinessInfoController.php:30
C:\work\test\tests\app\Http\Controllers\BusinessInfoControllerTest.php:17
C:\Users\chew\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:188
C:\Users\chew\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:118
```

On my controller, it error out on this line.

```
public function getUsers(Request $request, InfoRequest $infoRequest)
{

    $this->validate($request, $infoRequest->ruleGetInfo());
    ....
}
```

While on the InfoRequest:

```
public function ruleGetInfo()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

I'm not sure why is it looking for a `validateTest` method. I even tried adding it on my phpunit test file and the actual controller file itself (just to test things out) but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Extra comma remove Use this `public function getUsers(Request $request, InfoRequest $infoRequest){` instead of `public function getUsers(Request $request, InfoRequest, $infoRequest)
{`

Comment: Removed extra comma. Though it has nothing to do with the error stated. It is just a typo on my end typing it down here.

Comment: which version of lumen are you using?

Comment: I am using Lumen 5.3.3

Comment: add your test file